# Handling session already started & set_cookie_params

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I've seen lots of examples about how to detect if a PHP session is started. What I can't find is how to handle cookie params if one is started.

Here's my code.  This is in a WordPress plugin. If another plugin starts the session, I get a warning about setting cookie params when this plugin runs.  How do I correctly set these params if another plugin has already started a session without doing a session_destroy and goofing up the other plugin's session?

```
    $session_length = (60 * 60) * 8; // 1 hour x 8 = 8 hours
    session_set_cookie_params($session_length, "/", null, false, true);
    session_start();
    setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + $session_length);
```

Comment: Sessions can only be started once.

Comment: I fully understand that.  That does not answer the question of how to set cookie params once a session is already started.

Comment: What is the intention of your script?    What do you want to achive?  Plese look at the annotations in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 0):

Overall your question -as currently put- seems too general. With the limited information you have given at this point I **do not** feel you should be dealing with the session generally unless you're **sure** you want to be the only one doing so.

Because `$_SESSION` is a global special case in PHP and because you state "This is in a WordPress plugin" you are always going to be an arbitary `one-of-many` plugin for dealing with a session that can be used/set/unset by any other of the `one-of-many` WordPress plugins that any WordPress admin ***can and will*** have loaded outside of your plugin's control.

Therefore:

You need to identify the `$_SESSION` has started already (with `session_name()`) to check if:

- a) there's a session there already and then
- b) if that session is your own

and act accordingly; in this case, destroy their session and then set your own with its own parameters.

---

And why the hell are you, in 2021, trying to set a session via a WordPress plugin with security = `false`?! THAT needs to be improved and updated before you do anything else.

Comment: Thanks, session_name is what I was looking for.  As for the secure=false, this is currently on a local test server without a cert. I hope you're wearing a helmet. People who ride motorcycles and jump to conclusions should always have one handy.